# Set language in c# application

Tags: c#, mysql

I have problem with set language in c# application connected on a MySQL db.

The server in use is a Windows Server 2003 in english language.

I need set the output of query in german language.

I tried the queries sequence in MySQL db and the output is correct.

```
mysql> SET lc_time_names = 'de_DE';

SELECT
    CONCAT(
        MONTHNAME(
            STR_TO_DATE(Eng_Month, '%Y-%m')
        ),
        ' ',
        YEAR (
            STR_TO_DATE(Eng_Month, '%Y')
        )
    ) AS DE_Date
FROM
    tbl_month;
Query OK, 0 rows affected

+-----------+
| DE_Date   |
+-----------+
| Juni 2014 |
| Juli 2014 |
+-----------+
2 rows in set
```

If try the same solution in c# application the output is only english.

This is beginning to make me believe my structure as a whole is not correct.

What am I missing ?

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me in working this problem.

My code below:

```
   protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        Page.Culture = "de-DE";
        Page.UICulture = "de-DE";
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            InitializeCulture();
            MonthLanguage();
            GridViewBind();
            Response.Write(Page.Culture + "<br />");
            Response.Write("Your current culture: " + System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DisplayName + "<br />");
        }
    }

   protected void MonthLanguage()
    {
        using (OdbcConnection cn =
            new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString))
        {
            sql = " SET lc_time_names = 'de_DE'; "; 

            using (OdbcCommand command =
                new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
            {
                try
                {
                    command.Connection.Open(); 
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw new ApplicationException("operation failed!", ex);
                }
                finally
                {
                    command.Connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public DataTable GridViewBind()
    {
        sql = " ... ";

        try
        {
            dadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(sql, cn);
            dset = new DataSet();
            dset.Clear();
            dadapter.Fill(dset);
            DataTable dt = dset.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            dadapter.Dispose();
            dadapter = null;
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just execute `SET lc_time_names` in the same connection as your query. You can make `MonthLanguage` accept a parameter for the connection and just call it on the connection you're using for your query.

```
protected void MonthLanguage( OdbcConnection conn )
{
    var sql = " SET lc_time_names = 'de_DE'; "; 

        using (OdbcCommand command =
            new OdbcCommand(sql, conn ))
        {
            try
            {
                command.Connection.Open(); 
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("operation failed!", ex);
            }
        }
}

public DataTable GridViewBind()
{
    sql = " ... ";
    using( var cn = new OdbcConnection(
           ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString) )
    {
        try
        {
             MonthLanguage( cn ); // This sets the language for this connection

             dadapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(sql, cn);
             dset = new DataSet();
             dset.Clear();
             dadapter.Fill(dset);
             DataTable dt = dset.Tables[0];
             GridView1.DataSource = dt;
             GridView1.DataBind();

             return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            dadapter.Dispose();
            dadapter = null;
            cn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your MonthLanguage creates a connection, sets the language, and then closes the connection which looses the effect of setting the language. When you fill your dataset, it uses a new connection which has the default language. You can try a couple of things:

In GridViewBind set your SQL as:

```
sql = "SET lc_time_names = 'de_DE'; Select .....";
```

(This would work in SQL Server; I don't know about MySQL.)

Alternatively, just return the base DateTime column from the SQL and use the fact that you're in the correct language locale in the C# code to format it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Solved in MySQL, using RazorView / c#.

See example:

```
var tmp_data = db.Query("SET lc_time_names = 'it_IT'; SELECT MONTHNAME(yourdate) AS MONTH FROM orders GROUP BY MONTH(yourdate), YEAR(yourdate) ORDER BY  yourdate DESC");
```